# Testing Goroutine That My Code Does Not Wait For

Tags: unit-testing, testing, concurrency, go, goroutine

I have a function that is executed concurrently. It's task is to run a command line method, logging an error if there is one. My main thread of execution does not wait for this method to finish. It simply returns optimistically.

How do I *test* my function? Assuming that I give it a `cmdStr`, such as `{"sleep", "1"}`, that works but doesn't return instantly, how can I get my test to wait for this function to finish?

I want to ensure that the actual program that runs this does *not* have to wait for it to finish.

```
func runCmd(cmdStr []string, errChan chan error) {
  cmd := exec.Command(cmdStr...)
  var out bytes.Buffer
  cmd.Stdout = &out
  err := cmd.Start()
  if err != nil {
    errChan <- err
    return
  }
  // Command started successfully, so our caller can continue.
  errChan <- nil
  err = cmd.Wait()
  if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a wait group

```
wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
errc := make(chan error)
wg.Add(1)
go func() {
    runCmd([]string{"sleep", 1}, errc)
    wg.Done()
}()
err <- errc
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
wg.Wait()
```

Comment: Except that I don't wait to wait for runCmd to finish. At least, I would prefer not to. The calling function in this case is meant to be short lived, used simply to kick off the potentially longer running `runCmd`.

Comment: @davemankoff then you risk that your program exists without all work finishing. But if you really don't want to wait, your main program can ignore the done channel and your testing code can use the done channel.

Comment: If I ignore the done channel, won't runCmd block, waiting for it to be read from? http://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types. It seems like I could maybe make it buffered, but it's unclear to me the exact behavior there if I never read from it.

Comment: I updated my answer to use a wait group instead.  This will work but your main program should probably stick around to handle any error reporting that might occur from your exec commands.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method to aware all goroutings done is to add `select{}` as last `main.main()` statement. But `main()` will never return this way and you should kill process explicitly.
It's also more gentle `runtime.Goshed()` to wait for others, but it can't provide such a strong guarantee.
And the canonical way would be

```
wg := sync.WaitGroup
...
wg.Add(1)
go runCmd(...)
...
wg.Wait()
```